# What does this C++ setter/getter pattern break?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, glsl, getter-setter

#### Using the GLSL syntax in C++

I wrote custom vector classes such as `vec2`, `vec3` etc. that mimic the GLSL types and look roughly like this:

```
struct vec3
{
    inline vec3(float x, float y, float z)
      : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}
    union { float x, r, s; };
    union { float y, g, t; };
    union { float z, b, p; };
};
```

Operations on vectors are implemented this way:

```
inline vec3 operator +(vec3 a, vec3 b)
{
    return vec3(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
}
```

This allows me to create vectors and access their components using a GLSL-like syntax and perform operations on them almost as if they were numeric types. The unions allow me to refer to the first coordinate indifferently as `x` or as `r`, as is the case in GLSL. For instance:

```
vec3 point = vec3(1.f, 2.f, 3.f);
vec3 other = point + point;
point.x = other.b;
```

#### The problem of swizzling

But GLSL also allows swizzled access, even with holes between components. For instance `p.yx` behaves like a `vec2` with `p`’s `x` and `y` swapped. When no component is repeated, it is also an lvalue. Some examples:

```
other = point.xyy; /* Note: xyy, not xyz */
other.xz = point.xz;
point.xy = other.xx + vec2(1.0f, 2.0f);
```

Now this could be done using standard getters and setters such as `vec2 xy()` and `void xy(vec2 val)`. This is what the [GLM library](http://glm.g-truc.net/) does.

#### Transparent getter and setter

However, I devised this pattern that lets me do exactly the same in C++. Since everything is a POD-struct, I can add more unions:

```
template<int I, int J> struct MagicVec2
{
    friend struct vec2;
    inline vec2 operator =(vec2 that);

private:
    float ptr[1 + (I > J ? I : J)];
};

template<int I, int J>
inline vec2 MagicVec2<I, J>::operator =(vec2 that)
{
    ptr[I] = that.x; ptr[J] = that.y;
    return *this;
}
```

And *eg.* the `vec3` class becomes (I simplified things a bit, for instance nothing prevents `xx` from being used as an lvalue here):

```
struct vec3
{
    inline vec3(float x, float y, float z)
      : x(x), y(y), z(z) {}

    template<int I, int J, int K>
    inline vec3(MagicVec3<I, J, K> const &v)
      : x(v.ptr[I]), y(v.ptr[J]), z(v.ptr[K]) {}

    union
    {
        struct { float x, y, z; };
        struct { float r, g, b; };
        struct { float s, t, p; };

        MagicVec2<0,0> xx, rr, ss;
        MagicVec2<0,1> xy, rg, st;
        MagicVec2<0,2> xz, rb, sp;
        MagicVec2<1,0> yx, gr, ts;
        MagicVec2<1,1> yy, gg, tt;
        MagicVec2<1,2> yz, gb, tp;
        MagicVec2<2,0> zx, br, ps;
        MagicVec2<2,1> zy, bg, pt;
        MagicVec2<2,2> zz, bb, pp;
        /* Also MagicVec3 and MagicVec4, of course */
    };
};
```

Basically: I use a union to mix the vector’s floating-point components with a magic object which is not really a `vec2` but can be cast implicitly to a `vec2` (because there’s a `vec2` constructor allowing it), and can be assigned a `vec2` (because of its overloaded assignment operator).

I am very satisfied with the result. The GLSL code above works and I believe I get decent type safety. And I can `#include` a GLSL shader in my C++ code.

#### Limitations

Of course there are limitations. I know of the following ones:

- `sizeof(point.xz)` will be `3*sizeof(float)` instead of the expected `2*sizeof(float)`. This is by design and I do not know whether this could be problematic.
- `&foo.xz` cannot be used as a `vec2*`. This should be OK because I only ever pass these objects by value.

So my question is: **what may I have overlooked that will make my life difficult with this pattern?** Also, I have not found this pattern anywhere else yet, so if anyone knows its name I am interested.

Note: I wish to stick to C++98, but I do rely on the compiler allowing type-punning through unions. My reason for not wanting C++11 yet is the lack of compiler support on several of my target platforms; all the compilers that are of interest to me support type punning, though.

Comment: Because you're using C++98 (C++11 doesn't have this problem), you're invoking UB when you read a value from a union that was not the last value written in that union

Comment: @SethCarnegie: you are right, I do rely on the compiler explicitly supporting this; I am adding a note about it.

Comment: I don't see anything that would work as a proper getter here; given a `vec3 v1`, there appears to be no way for `v1.xz` to be assigned correctly to an actual `vec2 v2`, since it doesn't look like anything reorders the elements (`v1.z` would have to go into `v2.y`, which is a different offset into the vector). Did you leave that out of the post, or am I missing something?

Comment: @MichaelMadsen: see how the reordering is done in the `vec3::vec3(MagicVec3<>const&)` constructor. I omitted it for brevity, but there is of course one for `vec2`, too. Since that constructor is not `explicit`, any method taking a `vec2` will also implicitly accept a `MagicVec2`. The conversion is therefore delayed until the contents are actually needed.

Comment: @SethCarnegie: all members of the union have the same type, hence their address may alias, so I think it's defined. What requires compiler support would be to read/write to differnet union members with a different type afaict.

Comment: An interesting bit of fact that may or may not be relevant (I leave that judgement to you) is that **graphics hardware does not have different vector sizes**, nor do most APIs. The hardware has a set of float4 registers, and setting a "float2" sets the first two components of that. Shader compilers and optimizers use that property heavily, as do authors and artists, packing variables and data into the extra components. You will simplify your life **a ton** by making everything a float4 and 0-filling/disregarding the unused components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short: I think that it is difficult to make sure that this pattern works - that's why you are asking. Moreover, this pattern could be replaced by a standard proxy pattern, for which correctness is easier to guarantee. I have to admit though that the storage overhead of a proxy-based solution is a problem when the proxies are created statically.

## Correctness of the above code

This is code where there is no obvious bug; but paraphrasing [C. A. R. Hoare](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Programming), this is not code where there is obviously no bug. Moreover, how hard is it to convince oneself that there is no bug?
I do not see any reason why the pattern would not work - but it is not so easy to prove (even informally) that it will work. In fact, trying doing a proof could fail and point out to some problems.
To be safe, I would disable all implicitly-generated constructors/assignment operators for `MagicVecN` classes, just to avoid considering all the associated complications (see subsection below); however doing that is forbidden, because for union members one cannot override the implicitly defined copy assignment operator, as explained by the standard draft I have and by GCC's error message:

```
member ‘MagicVec2<0, 0> vec3::<anonymous union>::xx’ with copy assignment operator not allowed in union
```

In the attached gist, I instead provide an implementation manually to be safe.

Note that MagicVec2's assignment operator should accepts its parameter by **const** reference (see example below, where this works); implicit conversions still happen (the const reference will point to the created temporary; this would not work without the const qualifier).

### Almost problems, but not quite

I thought a found a bug (which I didn't), but it is still somewhat interesting to consider - just to see how many cases must be covered to rule out potential bugs. Would `p.xz = p.zx` produce the correct results? I thought that `MagicVec2`'s implicit assignment operator would be invoked, leading to incorrect results; in fact, it isn't (I believe) because `I` and `J` are different and part of the type. What when the type is the same?
`p.xx = q.rr` is safe, but `p.xx = p.rr` is tricky (even though it might be stupid, but it should still not corrupt memory): is the implicitly-generated assignment operator `memcpy`-based? The answer seems to be no, but if yes, this would be a `memcpy` between overlapping memory intervals, which is undefined behavior.

### UPDATE: An actual problem

As noticed by the OP, the default copy assignment operator is also invoked for the expression `p.xz = q.xz`; in that case, it will in fact also copy the `.y` member. As mentioned above, the copy assignment operator cannot be disabled or modified for datatypes which are part of an union.

## The proxy pattern

Moreover, I believe that there is a much simpler solution, namely the proxy pattern (which you are partially using). `MagicVecX` should contain a pointer to the containing class instead of `ptr`; this way you need no trick using unions.

```
template<int I, int J> struct MagicVec2
{
    friend struct vec2;
    inline MagicVec2(vec2* _this): ptr(_this) {}
    inline vec2 operator=(const vec2& that);
private:
    float *ptr;
};
```

I tested this by compiling (but not linking) this code, which sketches the proposed solution: https://gist.github.com/1775054. Note that the code is not complete nor tested - one should also override the copy constructor of `MagicVecX`.

Comment: Well thanks a lot for the thorough analysis, suggestions and fixes! I am not sure I should update the code in the question, but I fixed `operator=` to take a const reference in my personal codebase, as per your suggestion. To answer a few of your points: `p.xz = p.zx` works because the compiler is forced to create a temporary `Vec2`. Assigning `p.xx` should be disallowed; I fixed that simply by marking `xx` and others `const`. But you raise the interesting point that `p.xz = q.xz` clobbers `p.y` because of the implicit assignment operator. This is indeed a real bug!

Comment: By the way, the reason I do not wish to use the proxy pattern is because it changes the object's size -- since on some platforms _eg._ `vec4` is aliased to a MMX or AltiVec vector of 4 floats, I cannot have its size be anything but 16 bytes.

Comment: Well it seems that the whole pattern collapses because C++98 won't let me disable the implicit assignment operator. Could you maybe make it clearer that `p.xz = q.xz` will fail, so that I can accept your answer? Thanks.

Comment: Actually I hadn't thought about 'p.xz = q.xz', although I did say that I feared the implicit assignment operator was a problem.

Comment: I made a small update to the answer. Now it'd make sense to rewrite it, but it would take too much time.

Comment: Well your contribution was undoubtedly key to finding that bug. Though I'm very disappointed that the pattern doesn't work, the bounty is yours :-) Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, I have found one problem already, though not directly with the code above. If `vec3` is somehow made a template class in order to support *eg.* `int` in addition to `float`, and the `+` operator becomes:

```
template<typename T>
inline vec3<T> operator +(vec3<T> a, vec3<T> b)
{
    return vec3<T>(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
}
```

Then this code will not work:

```
vec3<float> a, b, c;
...
c = a.xyz + b;
```

The reason is that figuring the arguments for `+` will require both template argument deduction (`T = float`) **and** an implicit conversion (from `MagicVec3<T,0,1,2>` to `vec3<T>`, which is not allowed.

There is however a solution acceptable for me: write all possible explicit operators.

```
inline vec3<int> operator +(vec3<int> a, vec3<int> b)
{
    return vec3<int>(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
}

inline vec3<float> operator +(vec3<float> a, vec3<float> b)
{
    return vec3<float>(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y, a.z + b.z);
}
```

This will also let me define rules for implicit promotion, for instance I can decide that `vec3<float> + vec3<int>` is legal and will return a `vec3<float>`.